# Insert into two different databases

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert into two different databases using MySQL;-

```
`$this->sql = "INSERT INTO tblfixedfare SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '$fieldDay' FROM tblfixedfare UNION SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '2', '$fieldNight' FROM tblfixedfare,INSERT INTO tblfixedfaresetup SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '$fieldFrompc', '1', '2' FROM tblfixedfaresetup UNION SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '$fieldTopc', '2', '2' FROM tblfixedfaresetup";`
```

There is not a problem with each insert, as both insert two rows into each table individually.

How would I get both of these to execute at the same time? At the moment I get the following error:

Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near`

```
'INSERT INTO tblfixedfaresetup SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, 'DE115', '1', '2'' at line 2SQL: INSERT INTO tblfixedfare SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '1', '20' FROM tblfixedfare UNION SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, '2', '30' FROM tblfixedfare UNION
                                INSERT INTO tblfixedfaresetup SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, 'DE115', '1', '2' FROM tblfixedfaresetup UNION SELECT NULL, MAX(FixedFareID)+1, 'DE116', '2', '2' FROM tblfixedfaresetup`
```

Comment: What API are you using - MySQLi, PDO, mysql_*()?  Most of them don't support executing multiple queries in one statement (MySQLi does).  Generally you need to execute _two_ separate statements.  (from the query variables, I'm assuming this is `mysql_*()`)

Comment: And even if you could execute two statements, the separator between them would be `;` rather than `,`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski from my experience PDO supports multiple queries at once just fine with the semicolon separator.

Comment: I am using PDO, I will try using `;` instead

Answer (score 0):

you can use two different connection and separate insert query to insert in two database.
or use databasename.table name when insert.
Thanks